# Board game functions

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have made a program to a board game. My problem is a function, so that certain fields transport the player back or forward. Apparently the thing I did doesn't work.

```
int numbers()
{
int maxscore;
int numbers[10];
maxscore = enter();
srand(time(NULL));
int nonumbers[3] = {0, 1, maxscore};  //to initialize the scores there shouldn't be a badfield
numbers[10] = rand() % maxscore + 1;
if(numbers[10] == nonumbers[3])
{
    numbers[10] = rand() % maxscore + 1;
}
return numbers;


}

int badfields = numbers();
if(score[i] == badfields)
       {
           printf("Player %d. goes 5 fields backwards", playershown);
           score[i] = score[i] - 5;
           printf("This player is now in %d Field", score[i]);
       }
```

Somehow I have to repeat the process of entering the maximum score.

Comment: People are more likely to answer your questions if: 1/ your question title tells something about the actual problem you're having; 2/ you format your code so that it is easy to read; 3/ the code you provide is compilable as-is; 4/ you describe the actual problem precisely. "The thing I did doesn't work" isn't a description. Also, make sure you fix all the errors your compiler tells you about when you compile with full warnings enabled and both with and without optimizations.

Comment: Ok, thanks Mat, but that doesn't really help me with my problem, except the answering part, thanks for that. But I have solved every problem the compiler showed me, and the programm works, just not the way I wanted it to

Comment: Address the 4 numbered issues I mentioned above if you want help.

Comment: Learn arrays, their indexing ...

Comment: In `if(numbers[10] == nonumbers[3])` you break both the arrays since they must be indexed from `[0]` to `[length-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I won't directly answer the "question" because there is no "question" to be answered. As others have pointed out in the comments, you need to be more specific and provide a proper description of your problem. But I can still provide the following feedback:

It seems to me you don't quite understand arrays and their indexing. For example, this line should give you a segmentation fault error, or at the very least make a comparison with an unknown value:

```
if(numbers[10] == nonumbers[3])
```

This is because your `nonumbers` array has 3 elements, and thus they should be addressed as `nonumbers[0]`, `nonumbers[1]` or `nonumbers[2]` (or, in general, as [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) put it in the comments, from `nonumbers[0]` to `nonumbers[array_lenght-1]`). `nonumbers[3]` will access an undefined position in memory. Your problem could be related to this.

> Note that neither me nor anybody is going to review your entire code
>   to find the error. As stated above, please be more specific.

Also, are you sure you got rid of all compiler errors? Because further down your code you have an uninitialized variable `i`. To be sure you got rid of all potentially nasty errors, open the terminal (I'm assuming you are on linux) and use the following command to compile your program:

```
gcc *.c -Wall -Wextra -o program
```

Then run it with:

```
./program
```